Using a non-bundled version of Pandoc with Quarto for .qmd files
I am using Quarto 1.5.56 and am wondering if there is a way to use a version of Pandoc that is not bundled with Quarto when knitting a .qmd file instead of an .rmd file.
I have already installed the latest version of Pandoc, which is 3.3, as shown below:
> pandoc -v
pandoc 3.3
Features: +server +lua
Scripting engine: Lua 5.4
User data directory: /home/a6m1/.local/share/pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2024 John MacFarlane. Web: https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is no
warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.

However, when I run quarto pandoc -v, it appears that Quarto is using its bundled version of Pandoc, which is not the latest version I have installed and intend to use:
> quarto pandoc -v
pandoc 3.2
Features: +server +lua
Scripting engine: Lua 5.4
User data directory: /home/a6m1/.local/share/pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2024 John MacFarlane. Web: https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is no
warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.

1.1 Use a Pandoc version not bundled with the RStudio IDE | R Markdown Cookbook suggests the following command for knitting an .rmd file, but does this solution also work with .qmd files?
pandoc::with_pandoc_version(
  version = '2.9.1',
  rmarkdown::render('input.Rmd')
)


1.1 Use a Pandoc version not bundled with the RStudio IDE | R Markdown Cookbook
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-pandoc.html

